# null pointer exception when programming for android phone from processing IDE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, processing-ide

i am relatively new to java programming and programming for android and have been experimenting with android bluetooth comms using the Ketai library for the processing IDE specifically for use with android and tried to run the example program bluetoothcursors.pde that comes with the library but i keep getting the "application has stopped unexpectedly" error and the console indicates a null pointer exception error. The actual output is below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ketai.net.bluetooth.KBluetoothListener.<init>(KBluetoothListener.java:56)
    at ketai.net.bluetooth.KetaiBluetooth.start(KetaiBluetooth.java:207)
    at processing.test.bluetoothcursors.BluetoothCursors.setup(BluetoothCursors.java:80)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

However i cant seem to see where the null pointer exception is coming from. I assume the null pointer exception relates to a variable that has not been instantiated properly. I have tried a process of elimination to try and isolate the cause but i get the same error but with slightly different source. I have also posted this question on the processing forum but have not received a reply. I just assumed that since it was part of the examples for the library it would work so maybe the error is being created somewhere else. I have tried other library examples and theses all work fine so i dont think its my setup. I also have other bluetooth programs working on android from processing but these use pure java code and are harder to follow.

I have had a look at some of the similar questions which have been sort-of helpful but i am still stuck.

I have set the correct bluetooth etc permissions and am using android version 2.3.3 and processing version 2.0.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Please post your code to help you

Comment: Instead of BIG explanation, sharing glimpse of `KBluetoothListener` will help a lot

Comment: KBlueToothListener is part of the Ketai library and the error seems to be on line 56 (https://code.google.com/p/ketai/source/browse/trunk/ketai/src/ketai/net/bluetooth/KBluetoothListener.java?r=428#56). The only possible thing to throw an exception here is the mAdapter variable, which comes from KetaiBluetooth and is initialized on line 90 (http://code.google.com/p/ketai/source/browse/trunk/ketai/src/ketai/net/bluetooth/KetaiBluetooth.java?r=428#90)... But if the library could not see the Adapter it would throw "No Bluetooth Support." in the applet and you don't report anything like that...

Comment: @user3243808 Petros' advice is very good. It seems the Ketai library can't initialize bluetooth properly in your case. One thing you could do is surround the block of code that initializes ketai bluetooth in a try/catch (e.g. `try{//init ketai bluetooth here}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace()}` - this wouldn't solve your problem though, it would just potentially stop your app from crashing so you can display in error message to the user. Try one of the Ketai samples like BluetoothCursors first. If that works, try to modify that to your use. If the sample doesn't work...

Comment: ...there's something wrong either with your setup or the library, in which case your should try to contact the library developer. Hopefully  the BluetoothCursors sample works and you can carry on from there

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, its in the BluetoothCursors example that the error is occurring which is odd since as this is part of the ketai library examples it should work. So i will take your advice and contact the library developer and see what happens. Cheers.

Comment: It could be something such as that your device may not support bluetooth, you may not have bluetooth permission in the manifest, or the bluetooth stack on the device may be in a broken state.